# Where's the service status page for Programming Cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I've searched wolframcloud.com and found none.

It would be good to know, because I am getting a range of apparently random failures from "Tag List ... is Protected" to "possible crash" (!) to "Cloud sync failure" whereas no problems on other web apps. If the servers are undergoing maintenance, I'll give them a rest for now. (And yes I know this is marked BETA.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: It seems that you might have accidentally created a second user account.  You can [request a merge as described in the site FAQ.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: I think it will be impossible to answer this question here, because we are all just users, and mostly of *Mathematica* at that, so we do not have special insights into the inner workings of most of WRI's products and technologies. This seems a better topic to ask about on the Wolfram Community, where (more of) WRI's own staff are active, and where there are more people who use the various not-*Mathematica* products.